# Jump Game in recursion

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

I am trying to test my abilities to understand well the recursion so I gave myself the task to do the Jump Game exercice in recursion

*Given an array of non-negative integers, you are initially positioned at the first index of the array.Each element in the array represents your maximum jump length at that position.Your goal is to reach the last index in the minimum number of jumps.*

https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game-ii/

I tried to to this part of code but It does not appear on the debugger so I am not really seeing the problem in this

```
def function(array, index, counter):
    if index >= len(array):
        return counter
    min_step = float('inf')
    for i in range(1, array[index]):
        min_step = min(min_step, function(array, index + i, counter + 1))

    return min(min_step, function(array[1:], index, counter))
```

If someone can tell if I am in the right direction of thinking

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is pretty good, just a few fixes:

1. You want to get to the last index, which is `len(array) - 1`, not `len(array)`.
2. You want to enable jumps to a distance of up to **and including** the current array value, so you need `range(1, array[index] + 1)` instead of `range(1, array[index])`.
3. `min_step` already contains the least amount of jumps. I'm not sure what you're trying to return but you can just `return min_step`.

With that in mind:

```
def function(array, index, counter):
    if index >= len(array) - 1:
        return counter
    min_step = float('inf')
    for i in range(1, array[index] + 1):
        min_step = min(min_step, function(array, index + i, counter + 1))

    return min_step
```

Comment: Just to be sure the time complexity is O(n+max(array)) ?